# detecting 2 n bits integer addition overflow

Tags: arithmetic

Can somebody prove that when we add 2 bit integers and if there is an overflow then the result always will be lesser than the 2 operands used??

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd comic.](http://xkcd.com/571/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are the numbers you are adding. Suppose that $0 \le a,b < 2^n$. Then we must have that $a+b - 2^n < a$ and $a+b - 2^n < b$. Hence if overflow occurs the result is smaller than $a$ or $b$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** $\rm\ \ \ a+b-c\ <\ a,b\ \iff\ a,b\ <\ c$